# Can you install QEMU on High Sierra?

Tags: high-sierra

Has anyone been able to install QEMU on High Sierra (10.13.6)?

On the wikipedia of qemu,
https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/Mac#Building_QEMU_for_macOS

it is stated:

- "The system requirements are: One of the two most recent versions of macOS (currently Catalina or Big Sur.) The clang compiler shipped with the version of Xcode for that OS X. GCC might also work, but we recommend clang."

But has any one succeeded in operating qemu of an earlier version from the download list here:
https://download.qemu.org/ for High Sierra?

Comment: Instead of Wikipedia, you should be getting this info from QEMU directly.  https://www.qemu.org/download/#macos  It can be installed via brew or MacPorts.  What version are you specifically looking for?

Comment: Homebrew won't work as it only supports the most recent macOS versions - I think 3

Comment: Alsoe see comment from thet page "QEMU requires the most recent macOS version that is currently available. Support for the last previous version will be dropped two years after the current version has been released or when Apple drops support for it, whatever comes first."

Comment: So QEMU does not support High Sierra now - the best chance is try macports as they do attempt to support old versions of macOS